# How to Put div between table row and toggle on click?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I put div inside a table row and toggle its visibility using a button.

I am creating a table row using Angularjs ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results" >
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canname}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canbloodgroup}}</td>
    <td>{{result.cangender}}</td>
    <td>Button</td>  
</tr>
```

I want to put a div of table width  between each row, how can I do this?

Comment: Clarify your question.

Comment: div in tables isn't proper html

Comment: i want   to  show div  on  click  button  below that respective row

Comment: Probably a copy paste error, but you need a closing angle bracket on `</tr` at the end.

Comment: You can't use `div` in direct child of `table`. Also you should use `tr` with particular class and write `div` in that `tr`.

Comment: Add another `tr` with `colspan=9999` and put your div in that

Answer (score 5):

```
<table ng-repeat="result in results">
<tr>
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canname}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canbloodgroup}}</td>
    <td>{{result.cangender}}</td>
    <td>Button</td>  
</tr>
<tr ng-if="true/false">
  <td colspan=4>
    <div>
      <p>{{things-you wnat to show}}</p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Well you can't put a div in between rows, but you can create sperate table  with div as a row 
Maybe It will fullfill your requirement . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments , some table elements only allow specific children tags

You could repeat `<tbody>` and have 2 rows in each

```
<tbody ng-repeat="result in results">
  <tr ng-if="someVariable">
    <td colspan="5">Your other content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canname}}</td>
    <td>{{result.canbloodgroup}}</td>
    <td>{{result.cangender}}</td>
    <td ng-click="someVariable = ! someVariable">Button</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Adjust the display behavior to whatever it is you want

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a div but you can place **tbody** instead.